# List of Lists python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list assigned to the variable my_list.

```
my_list = [[(1, 2)], [(4, 8), (2, 3)], [(1, 6), (6,7), (8,9)]].
```

I need to find the length of `my_list`, but `len(my_list)` only returns 3.

I want it to return 6. I am new to python. Is there any Python function that will return the full length of `my_list` including the nested lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```py
my_list  = [[(1, 2)], [(4, 8), (2, 3)], [(1, 6), (6,7), (8,9)]]
length = len(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list)))
print(length)
# >>> 6
```

Edit: If you have to do this a lot, and don't want to type `len(list(itertools.chain....` each time, you can create your own function.

```py
def my_len(arr):
    return len(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(arr)))
```

Then call `my_len` on any list of lists you need the length of.

```py
my_list  = [[(1, 2)], [(4, 8), (2, 3)], [(1, 6), (6,7), (8,9)]]
print(my_len(my_list))
# > 6
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no built in function like that, but you can get it easily with a generator expression:

```
length = sum(len(inner_list) for inner_list in my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the list:

```
my_list  = [[(1, 2)], [(4, 8), (2, 3)], [(1, 6), (6,7), (8,9)]];
flat = [item for sublist in my_list  for item in sublist];
print (len(flat));
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
sum(len(x) for x in mylist)
```

basically its doing a little

> loop over the elements of "mylist". len(mylist) gives 3 because
>   obviously there are 3 elements in this "outer" list

. The lists nested inside each have their own number of elements, the sum function is just an easy way to run a counter over these elements.

sorry for my very blasphemous explanation, I am not a by programmer by training.

edit: i see someone has already posted this above